# What excel formula can be used to get the mean for the following data? And how to apply it?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I have my data as follows, the values in the spreadsheet are the quantities, while 'red','yellow', 'green' are the **categories**

```
items  place     red     green   yellow  
a      VA         1       7       9
b      VA         3       0       19
c      VA         5       1        0
d      VA         11      3        4
e      VA         2       2        1
a      NJ         0       0        3
b      NJ         3       0        9
c      NJ         2       4        0
d      NJ         0       5        6
e      NJ         2       7        1
a      MO         0       0        5
b      MO         1       0        4
c      MO         1       4        0
d      MO         0       0        5
e      MO         1       7        1
```

For each place-category combination, I would like to compute the mean of these quantities across all 5 items (a,b,c,d,e),

```
category  place  Avg_quantity
red        VA     ..
green      VA .   ..
yellow     VA     ..
 red       NJ     ..
green      NJ     ..
yellow     NJ     ..
 red       MO     ..
green      MO     ..
yellow     MO     ..
```

I tried using averageifs but it gives an error since my arguments length is different for category and place

Comment: powerquery will do it

Comment: Is there any excel formula to do it, instead?

Comment: See answer below.

Comment: A pivot table might be a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, in `J2` and drag down:

```
=AVERAGE(IF($B$2:$B$16=$I2,INDEX($C$2:$E$16, ,MATCH($H2,$C$1:$E$1,0))))
```

Entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> i.e. array formula

---

**Data**

[image: Data]

Excluding zeroes:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(INDEX($C$2:$E$16,,MATCH($H2,$C$1:$E$1,0)),INDEX($C$2:$E$16,,MATCH($H2,$C$1:$E$1,0)),">0",$B$2:$B$16,$I2)
```

Comment: Actually, i tried the above formula however it gives me different/incorrect average values:                                                                                     
       red VA 2.133333333
    green VA 2.666666667
    yellow VA 4.466666667
    red     NJ 0
   green NJ 0
  yellow NJ 4.466666667
   red  MO 0
   green MO 0
   yellow MO 0

Comment: With the same data as above?

Comment: Then you have made a mistake somewhere. Did you enter with ctrl + shift + enter.

Comment: How can I avoid averaging over 0's using the above formula?